# EF Core 2.1 Update causes record to be created in related table

Tags: linq, ef-core-2.1

I have an Address table and a State table in my db.  When I call update on an address record in EF Core, I provide an Id to an existing State record.  For some reason the query is inserting a new record into the State table instead of finding the existing record. I have my code below.

This is the service layer code that calls the data access:

```
public int UpsertContactInfo(ContactInfo contactInfo)
        {
var mailingAddress = new AddressEntity() {
            AddressLine1 = contactInfo.mailingAddressLine1,
            AddressLine2 = contactInfo.mailingAddressLine2,
            City = contactInfo.mailingCity,
            ZipCode = contactInfo.mailingZip,
            Id = contactInfo.mailingAddressId,
            State = new StateEntity(){
                Id = contactInfo.mailingStateId
            }
            };
_addressDataAccess.UpdateAddress(mailingAddress);
```

and here is my data access:

```
public int UpdateAddress(AddressEntity address)
        {
            _context.Addresses.Attach(address);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return (int)address.Id;
        }
```

ContactInfo:

```
using System;

namespace LandHawk.DataAccess.Entity
{
    public class ContactInfoEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
        public AddressEntity PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
        public int MailingAddressId { get; set; }
        public AddressEntity MailingAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

State:

```
using System;

namespace LandHawk.DataAccess.Entity
{
    public class StateEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

No special mapping is done. in my databaseContext:

```
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<AddressEntity> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StateEntity> States { get; set; }
...        
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<StateEntity>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<AddressEntity>()
                .Property(a => a.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

The Address Id is definitely set to 1 which matches an existing record in the state table in the db. however, when the call is made, a new state record is created.

Comment: Please also show `ContactInfo` and `State`, including how they are mapped.

Comment: `Attach` shouldn't perform add or update. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities), `Update` will perform add or update if affected entities use auto generated PKs.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. when I use update, the correct record is found in the State table, but all of the other data is nulled. would I have to get the state record first and then update address with the filled out state object? I'd like to just say, this address has a stateId of 1 and not have to go into the state table at all if possible.

Comment: Gert I've edited my post to include the requested info. Please let me know what you think. Thanks

Comment: Can you share address entity class ?

Comment: 1) Remove attach  replace it with `update` 2) replace `State = new StateEntity(){
                Id = contactInfo.mailingStateId
            }` it with `StateId=contactInfo.mailingStateId`